# Remove Path from PHP String front and back

Tags: php, string

i have bellow string in php and i want remove directory listing and get only the xml name

```
/usr/local/EDI/GTNexus/BookingConfirmation/test/PROCESSED/ELITESGGTN_30120180814_1410366355.XML_20180817135443
```

i want to return the string as  ELITESGGTN_30120180814_1410366355.XML.

i use below way but im not getting the expected result

to remove front i used this but not getting the expected outcome

```
$newfname = strstr($fname, '/');
```

Comment: [pathinfo()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) maybe?

Comment: yup pathinfo() worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explode on "/" and then find the last undescore from the last item and substring it.

```
$str = "/usr/local/EDI/GTNexus/BookingConfirmation/test/PROCESSED/ELITESGGTN_30120180814_1410366355.XML_20180817135443";
$arr = explode("/", $str);
$name = substr(end($arr), 0, strrpos(end($arr), "_"));
echo $name; //ELITESGGTN_30120180814_1410366355.XML
```

Comment: @kanishka How can pathinfo work? It can't know to remove the date at the end.

Comment: i remove date using different method after that.